# local version of Linked Movie Database at linkedmdb.org

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, owl, linkedmdb

i want to query from  Linked Movie Database at linkedmdb.org locally.
is there some rdf or owl version of it that can i download query locally instead of remotely
I tried to query it  and got the following error:

```
org.openjena.riot.RiotException: <E:\Applications\linkedmdb-latest-dump\linkedmdb-latest-dump.nt> Code: 11/LOWERCASE_PREFERRED in SCHEME: lowercase is preferred in this component
    org.openjena.riot.system.IRIResolver.exceptions(IRIResolver.java:256)
    org.openjena.riot.system.IRIResolver.access$100(IRIResolver.java:24)
    org.openjena.riot.system.IRIResolver$IRIResolverNormal.resolveToString(IRIResolver.java:380)
    org.openjena.riot.system.IRIResolver.resolveGlobalToString(IRIResolver.java:78)
    org.openjena.riot.system.JenaReaderRIOT.readImpl(JenaReaderRIOT.java:121)
    org.openjena.riot.system.JenaReaderRIOT.read(JenaReaderRIOT.java:79)
    com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.read(ModelCom.java:226)
    com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager.readModelWorker(FileManager.java:395)
    com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager.loadModelWorker(FileManager.java:299)
    com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager.loadModel(FileManager.java:250)
    ServletExample.runQuery(ServletExample.java:92)
    ServletExample.doGet(ServletExample.java:62)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:627)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a claim that there is a download from [this page](http://ckan.net/package/linkedmdb). Haven't tried it myself, so I don't know whether it's fresh or not.

Comment: i downloaded the file and its extension is .nt.How do i view it?

Comment: .nt means that the file is in N-Triples format, which is basically plain text. Depending on the size, you can open it in a text editor, or view it from the command line with a program like `cat` or `less` on Linux, or `type` (if I recall correctly) on Windows.

Comment: i have posted the error i am getting while querying the dump file

Answer (score 2):

There is a dump in ntriples format at this address:
http://queens.db.toronto.edu/~oktie/linkedmdb/
If you want to query it you may upload the dump files onto one local triple store such as 4store or jena (using the relational support). Other libraries and tools are available, depending on the language you're more familiar with.

If you need more information let me know.

Comment: i have posted the error i am getting while querying the dump file

Comment: Try to put the URI to the nt file in lowercase. In doubt there's a thread for this problem here: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/jena-dev/message/45128